# How to show Messages on a toast in Materializecss?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, materialize, toast

I am doing this `Toast` stuff from materialize together with Laravel 5.8. My problem now is the toast messages is returning an empty message during first call. This is what i have so far:

```html
<button type="submit" name="submit" form="lt-add-form" class="btn btn-small" id="lt-btn-save" style="border-radius: 0;" onclick="showToast({{ $errors }}, 3000)"><i class="fas fa-save"></i>Save</button>
```

and i have this javascript method:

```
function showToast(message, duration) {
    console.log(message['name']+" "+message['code']);
    if(message['name']){
        M.toast({html: message['name']});   
    }

    if(message['code']){
        M.toast({html: message['code']});   
    }
}
```

and also, on my first click on my save button. It gives me an undefined value just like the image below:

[image]

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As I read from the [document](https://materializecss.com/toasts.html) of MaterializeCss framework, you may pass arguments to the function toast in wrong way. It should be

```
M.toast({html: message, displayLength: duration})
```

Toast function take an argument as an object and will take html and displayLength property of the object to handle.

Comment: Indeed, it takes arguments but how can i solve the empty case? I mean, I read another tutorial which uses ```Materialize.toast()``` to output something. I just use ```M.toast(message, duration)``` to see why gives an undefined value. I don't know if it is because of Laravel or the materializecss.

Comment: It may caused because your `$errors`? I dont know what's `$errors` here so I can't help in this situation, maybe it caused by lavarel

Comment: On the tutorial that i am following, he is using that variable whenever a field validation arise so maybe that variable is constant in Laravel that takes care of all field validation?

Comment: Sorry Im not familiar with Lavarel, I thought you was asking about toast function of Materialize ...

Comment: No problem dude, I really appreciate your help. I just ask this question because i am not sure where the problem occurs on MaterializeCss or on the Laravel.